# How to define a register across all banks?

Tags: assembly, interrupt, pic

How can I define a register across all banks, in assembly, using a PIC16F887 or similar?

The file is supposed to be accessed without changing the STATUS bits.

I am trying to save the W register to a temp file (W_TEMP), before entering an interrupt routine.

From a Microchip document:

> The user register, W_TEMP, must be defined across all banks and must be defined at the same offset from the bank base address (i.e., W_TEMP is defined at 0x70 - 0x7F in Bank0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an interrupt occurs we need to save `W` and `STATUS`, but `STATUS` is already in the RAM and there is no instruction that move a register from a RAM location to another, so it must first be copied into `W` and then into the final destination.
This means we must save `W` and `STATUS` in this *exact* order.

1. Save `W`
2. Move `STATUS` into `W`
3. Save `W` (=`STATUS`)

We cannot modify `STATUS` before moving it into `W` or we'll never be able to restore its, now potentially lost, original value; since we move `STATUS` *after* saving `W` we cannot modify it to select a specific bank for saving `W`.

When an interrupt occurs any bank can be selected, so we *must be able to save `W` into any bank*.
If we use

```
 #define W_TEMP 0x40
```

This means that the addresses 0x40, 0x80+0x40, 0x100+0x100, 0x180+0x40 must be all be *considered* reserved by our program, since these locations can be overwritten suddenly by an interrupt.

This is the meaning of

> The user register, W_TEMP, must be defined across all banks and must be defined at the same offset from the bank base address

and it is a, maybe not very clear, warning that `W_TEMP` lives on all banks (or no bank at all if it is not saved). 
To "define" a register, mean to set an offset, a number, for it.

When it comes to save `STATUS` we must be careful, we cannot save it in any bank, because the ISR will modify it and we will lose the original `RP<1:0>` bits that tell the bank in which `STATUS` was saved.
So we need to pick a bank and use it, usually it is bank 0 because some chips have RAM only there.
Since setting the bank require to modify `STATUS` this seems an unsolvable problem.
Luckily we need to move `STATUS` to `W` to save it, so once it is in `W` we can use the `BCF` instruction to set the current bank without altering the original `STATUS` (now in `W`).

Example code

```
#define W_TEMP 0x70
#define STATUS_TEMP 0x71

MOVWF W_TEMP          ;Save W
SWAPF STATUS, W
BCF STATUS, RP0       ;Set bank0
MOVWF STATUS_TEMP     ;Save STATUS
```

**Note**: The use of `SWAPF` to save `STATUS` into `W` is necessary because `MOVF` change the `Z` flag, and cannot be used during restore.

After the ISR to restore the status the operations above must be performed in reverse order

```
SWAPF STATUS_TEMP, W
MOVWF STATUS              ;Restore STATUS (and bank)

;There is no load W from memory without affecting flags

SWAPF W_TEMP, F           ;We swap W_TEMP in place (no flags affected)
SWAPF W_TEMP, W           ;Then swap W_TEMP in W (this restoring W)
```

Some devices, like the PIC16F887, has a portion of RAM shared across all banks.
This portion is the last 16 bytes of every bank, offsets 0x70-0x7f.
In this case if `W_TEMP` and `STATUS_TEMP` are defined there we don't need to switch bank during the context saving:

```
#define W_TEMP 0x70
#define STATUS_TEMP 0x71

MOVWF W_TEMP
SWAPF STATUS, W 
MOVWF STATUS_TEMP
```

This explains the

> (i.e., W_TEMP is defined at 0x70 - 0x7F in Bank0)

part of the quote.

---

More information about the handling of interrupt can be found [in this Microchip document about it](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/31008a.pdf).
Beware that some comments are cryptic at best, misleading in the worst.

Comment: Wonderful. I was missing that "#define" trick. Thank you very much.